# I am not able to plot 2 sigma lines and color them diffferently

Tags: r, plot, standard-deviation

Suppose I have the following data, how can plot 2 sigma lines around its mean and how to color them red when a point is above the 2 sigma lines.

```
20  1   15  19  23
19  2   14  20  66
18  3   13  3   34
17  4   12  4   12
16  5   11  5   45
15  6   10  6   19
14  7   20  7   27
13  8   19  8   15
12  9   18  8   19
11  10  17  9   43
10  11  16  10  23
9   12  15  11  31
8   13  1   12  41
7   14  14  13  24
6   15  13  14  29
5   16  12  15  16
4   17  11  16  52
3   18  10  17  12
2   19  9   20  15
1   20  8   19  31
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  you can put together a solution with `?mean` and `?sd` (to find the 2-sigma limits) and `plot(...,col=ifelse(...,"black","red"))` ...

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am a newbie and in learning stage. SO really helps me in many ways.

Comment: yes, being a beginner is fine, but hopefully you have tried *something* before asking here, and more people will be more willing to pitch in with answers if you give even a relatively incoherent account of what you've tried/thought of ... does putting @ManojKumar's answer together with my hints above help you?

Comment: @BenBolker almost it does. I guess I can use SEGMENT for the rest plotting. just looking for the rest solution. Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

take the mean of the data,

```
say X <- c("your data")

meanX <- mean(X)
```

Then, calculate Standard deviation

```
sdX <- sd(X)
```

Then 2-sigma levels

```
Sigma2 <- meanX + c(-2, +2) * sdX
```

Finally, Plot them..

```
plot(X, typle = "l", main="", xlab="", ylab="", ) # just add the levels as you want
abline(h=meanX, col="red", lwd=2)
abline(h=Sigma2, lwd=2, col="blue")
```

Done!

Comment: But how can I plot different colors above and below Sigma2 lines?

Comment: you haven't done the last part of what the OP wanted (color points beyond +/-2 sigma red) ...

Comment: I agree. I just resolved the half of the issues, may be other half someone else can do.